# Using tokens from microsoft graph with sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to use tokens returned from Microsoft Graph with the SharePoint REST API or with SharePoint Client Context?

Answer (score 4):

You can access parts of the [SharePoint API through Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint), but I think you're asking about something different - using a single auth flow across services.

If you're using V1 auth (ie. you are explicitly specifying a 'resource' when getting you auth code and token), it's possible but you'll have two unique tokens - one for each resource. This is possible by [using multi-resource refresh tokens](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/) in which you can fetch a token for resource 2 by using the refresh token of resource 1.